# What I have to do to block requests if it is outside of my web application?

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api

I don't know if I'm saying clearly, but I'll try...

I need my API to block requests from anyone outside of my web app, I'm working with JWT authentication to do login.

I have no idea how I can start doing this, I don't know what I have to search/study, so I'm here to get help with themes that I can search.

Comment: Your question is vague. If you want to prevent people from creating another client to your api - that is technically impossible in general, but may be possible for some specific usecases (threats if you like), like javascript clients downloaded from other urls (see CORS). If you want to prevent CSRF attacks, that's definitely possible, and if your jwt is sent as a bearer token, it's mostly already done.

Comment: Hmmmm... I want to prevent people who trying to access my database, I thinking that Im not saying clearly... If anyone get the url, send it with postman, they can send any value to my db, I want to block this...

Comment: Is this some kind of a game and you want to prevent cheating? That is not technically possible this way.

Comment: maybe I can't express myself... It isn't a game, it's a human resources app... To control payments and somethings that need some security

Comment: Ok, so your question may be a software design/architecture one? The question is, why can't a user insert "x" into a table column where a day of week is supposed to be? Well, 1. because there is validation in the db (say an enum column), 2. there is validation in your model or equivalent, and 3. because there is no such endpoint that would do this. Basically you first authenticate your user (know who he is), and then you authorize each and every action, ie. on every api endpoint you check whether the authenticated user is allowed to perform the requested action *with the requested parameters*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In very broad terms, you want to implement an authorization scheme for your APIs. Doing so will let you control access based upon the entity (person or machine or another service/app) and other factors when someone calls your API. If you use JWT tokens as a means of conveying an authorization grant, have your API check that 1) token is present on the request 2) it's valid 3) it has all the right claims. If 1-3 are true, then authorize access and continue to the execution of your API's core logic.

Most likely your technology/solution stack already has a capability to do some or all of the above. Best place to start is to read more on how your stack handles these types of problems and go from there.

Comment: Do you have any material so that I can get deeper into this theme (JWT Claims)?

Comment: Hmm, I forgot to say, my identity and core projects are differents solutions.. They are on separeted solutions... Can be useless information, but I dont know how claims works, so only to add info..

Comment: @LeoHenrique What technology stacks are being used by your core and identity projects

Comment: Im using C# backend and Angular 5 frontend

Comment: Have a look at this [tutorial](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api)